# Capistrano deploy fails with "Cannot read username"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, capistrano

i wonder why my cap deployment fails.

I am using capistrano.

Here's my deploy.rb:

```
set :application, "gppb"
set :repository,  "git@github.com:AppSource/gppb.git"
set :scm, :git
set :user, "gppb.com"
set :deploy_to, "/home/gppb.com/apps/#{application}"
set :use_sudo, false
set :keep_releases, 5
# set :scm, :git # You can set :scm explicitly or Capistrano will make an intelligent guess based on known version control directory names
# Or: `accurev`, `bzr`, `cvs`, `darcs`, `git`, `mercurial`, `perforce`, `subversion` or `none`

role :web, "test.gppb.appsource.biz"                          # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app, "test.gppb.appsource.biz"                          # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,  "test.gppb.appsource.biz", :primary => true # This is where Rails migrations will run

# if you want to clean up old releases on each deploy uncomment this:
# after "deploy:restart", "deploy:cleanup"

# if you're still using the script/reaper helper you will need
# these http://github.com/rails/irs_process_scripts

# If you are using Passenger mod_rails uncomment this:
namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end
end
```

And here is the error:

[image]

To see the full image click here-> http://d.pr/i/wnIb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you should set your :user to "gppbv2". That's the parameter for the remote user on the server. Also, Unix usernames can't have periods in them.

Comment: This should be written inside the deploy.rb file?

Comment: Yes - you currently have :user set to "gppb.com", and that's not a valid username.

Comment: I'll try. Thank you. I'll get back to you. :)